# [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: x. This may cause an update error

Tags: vuejs2

I keep getting an error when I add an item to the array which has duplicate id.

i.e.

```
active_widgets:Array[4]
0:Object
    id:1
    name:"Text Blocks"
    selected:false
    set:false
1:Object
    id:3
    name:"Bibliographies/References"
    selected:false
    set:false
2:Object
    id:1
    name:"Text Blocks"
    selected:false
    set:false
3:Object
    id:2
    name:"Free Text"
    selected:"Test"
    set:false
```

In my scenario, 'id' element may be duplicate because the user can have the same widget on the page multiple times. I want to know if I can suppress or remove the warning that VueJS keeps throwing in the console.

Comment: That is because Vue wants to track items in an array by key. Try using :key = "<whatever the item name is>"

Comment: You could maybe suppress the error warning, but you'd still be getting update errors... The key needs to be unique.

Comment: You could also filter the array for duplicates before handing it to Vue.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Same key for different `v-for` loops causing this warning. You can avoid this using different key for different `v-for` loops.

```html
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i"></div>

    <div v-for="(item, i) in items2" :key="'A'+ i"></div>

    <div v-for="(item, i) in items3" :key="'B' + i"></div>
```

Here, `A` and `B` are just sample characters. You can basically use any character instead of those (just for uniqueness).

Comment: I'm confused. I just ran into this issue, but I thought keys just had to be unique per `v-for` loop. It's explained here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-key-does-the-key-need-to-be-unique-across-the-entire-component/28040

Comment: The key hint is that "Children of the same common parent must have unique keys"

Comment: This seems so silly but it works!!

Answer (score 29):

An alternative method:

Nesting the `v-for` elements inside any other element also seems to work.

```html
<div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items2" :key="index"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind to the `key` with a unique value. Not doing so will cause problems in your application when a change in data for a component with one key updates that component and the other component with the duplicate key.

You should assign a unique key property to each of the items in the `active_widgets` array and then bind the key to that property.

---

Without seeing any of your code, I don't know what your unique use case is. But here are a couple ways you could add a unique key property to the items in your array.

Here's an example doing that in the `created` method.

```
created() {
  this.active_widgets.forEach((item, index) => this.$set(item, 'key', index));
}
```

If you need to add a unique key when an item is added to this array, you could maintain a counter and increment it each time an addition is made:

```
let WidgetCount = 0;

export default {
  data() {
    return { active_widgets: [] }
  },
  methods: {
    addWidget(id, name) {
      this.active_widgets.push({ 
        id, 
        name, 
        selected: false,
        set: false, 
        key: WidgetCount++
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use different key name your problem will be solved.

```html
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i"></div>

    <div v-for="(item, j) in items2" :key="j" :data-index="j"></div> 
         or
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items2" :key="'i+item.id" :data-index="i"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<template v-for="it in items">
    <li :key="it.id + '-name'">{{it.name}}</li>
</template>
```

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7323

Answer (score 1):

```
<div v-for="(data, index)" in active_widgets" :key="index"> 
   {{data.id}}
   {{data.name}}
   {{data.selected}}
   {{data.set}}
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a unique key function to add keys to each of my arrays. Then using it in v-for as the key...

```
<div
            class="postBlob"
            v-for="{
              key,
              user,
              post,
              dateTime
            } in localPostData.slice().reverse()"
            :key="key"
          >
            <strong class="userBlobIndy">{{ user }} </strong>
            <h2 class="postBlobIndy">
              {{ post }}
              <p>{{ dateTime }}</p>
            </h2>
          </div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a best practice solution, the unique key generation is overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example

```
<template>
    <div  >
      
       <div v-for="categori in blogs"   id="blog-body" :key="categori.title" >

    <h2 >{{categori.title}}</h2>
    <h3>{{categori.contact }}</h3>
      
       </div>

    </div>
    
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            blogs:[
                {title:'this is title 1',contact : ' this is contact for test javascript'},
                {title:'this new title ',contact : ' this is contact for vue'},
                {title:'this is new title 2',contact : ' this is contact for  vue js'}
            ]
          
        }
    },
   
   
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this error, when using v-if, v-else inside the v-for like this:

```
<component-a v-if="somecondition === true" v-for="(val,index) in array">
:key="index"
...
</component-a>
<component-b v-else v-for="(val,index) in array">
:key="'new'+index"
...
</component-b>
```

Even though the indexes were different, I was getting this warning. To get around this, I put the conditionals outside of the v-for components like this:

```
<template v-if="somecondition === true">
  <component-a  v-for="(val,index) in array">
  :key="index"
  ...
  </component-a>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <component-b v-for="(val,index) in array">
  :key="'new'+index"
  ...
  </component-b>
</template>
```