# Duplicate keys detected: 'x'. This may cause an update error

Tags: vue.js

I use vueJs for my application and I use `v-for` loop some data. Then I am getting the following error.

> [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'x'. This may cause an update error.

Tried code:

```
<tr v-for="(num, index) in myArry" :key="index">
  <td v-text="num.volume_cap"></td>
</tr>
```

How can I stop this `warning`? Thank you.

Comment: please share a snippet of your array

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086657/vue-warn-duplicate-keys-detected-x-this-may-cause-an-update-error) help ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I updated the question with the array

Comment: @jcoleau nope mate. That was not

Comment: the code looks fine

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning, could it be coming from another v-for ? are you declaring the array in the data function of the options API ?

Comment: Vue expects the keys of a collection used in `v-for` to be unique. Since you use the `index` as key in the `v-for` posted, it is technically impossible for that `v-for` to throw the error. It's coming from a `v-for` which uses an object prop as `ìndex` and that prop doesn't have unique values across the collection being rendered. Could you post a [mcve]? Use codesandbox.io or similar if you need a multi-file online editor.

Comment: Which version of Vue.js are you using?

Comment: @MaxLiashuk Vue.js v2.6.12

Comment: @user_v12 if there is a unique key on the object just use it. `<tr v-for="(num) in myArry" :key="num.unique_key">`. If you don't have one try to add it somehow